# Hexadecimal value received after pgp decryption

Tags: java, encryption, pgp

I am using the following code to decrypt a pgp file.

http://sloanseaman.com/wordpress/2012/05/13/revisited-pgp-encryptiondecryption-in-java/

```
// Decrypt
pgpFileProcessor.setInputFile(encryptedFilePath);
pgpFileProcessor.setOutputFile(decryptedFilePath);
pgpFileProcessor.setKeyFile(privateKeyFile);
try {
    pgpFileProcessor.decrypt();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

When, the file is decrypted. My output is in hexadecimal format as follows:
8828 1d1b 00fe 1900 172e 2917 0400 0952
6081 
But I am expecting a text file after decryption with few lines of text. 
Is there something I am missing to do after decryption to make text file appear instead of hexadecimal file?

Comment: Can you show the code that you're using to call this library?  Nobody will be able to tell you what you're doing wrong, if you don't show what you're doing.

Comment: I link above has the code block that I am using for deryption and I also added the code I use to call the methods in the link above.

Comment: The code you've shown above doesn't work with the library at all.  The method names are all messed up.  Can you show the code that you actually used please?  Otherwise nobody can help you.  Also, where did your encrypted input come from?  Are you sure the output you're getting isn't correct?

Comment: When decryption fails, wrong key, encoding, options, etc the result will be essentially random and your output does not look random.